# How to do multiple joins in Sequel ORM for Ruby

Tags: sql, ruby, sequel

I am using the Sequel ORM. I have three tables, 'categories','merchants','products'.

Here are the models:

```
class Product < Sequel::Model
    many_to_one :merchants
end

class Merchant < Sequel::Model
    many_to_one :category
end
```

I need to fetch the products that are in a particular category. How do I do a JOIN for that?

If I need the products for a particular merchant, I can easily do:

```
@merchant = Merchant.first(:id=>1)
@merchant.products.each do |s|
...
end
```

But how can I get the products in a category when the category is related to merchants and merchants is related to the products table?

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way:

```
Product.
  select_all(:products).
  association_join(:merchant).
  where(:category_id=>category.id)
```

But it may be easiest to just add an association:

```
Category.many_to_many :products,
  :join_table=>:merchants,
  :right_key=>:id,
  :right_primary_key=>:merchant_id

category.products
```

Answer (score 0):

Get a category, iterate over the merchants that belong to that category, and push/append the products of this merchant to an array:

```
products = []
category = Category.find(:id=>1)
category.merchants.each do |m|
  p<<m.products
end
```

Comment: i think it would need to be iterated over m.products again eg, `m.products.each do |m|... end`. is there a way to do a JOIN obtain a similar result?